# Is there a way to not execute afterSave Cloud Code handler after Parse Object save?

Tags: parse-platform

I am having a Parse Cloud function that saves Parse Objects and I don't want to execute afterSave of the saved Parse Objects from the cloud function.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the afterSave trigger?

Comment: When trigger Parse Object save from cloud function, before and after save cloud code was not getting user in request headers. Because of which we wanted to call the before | after save conditionally. But will change the function in cloud code accordingly.